# More efficient way of creating a list from permuations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two different lists.

```
a = ['A','B','C','D']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

what I want to do is create a list of lists based on all the possible permutations. Something along the lines of.

```
[[('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('D',4)]
,[('A',1),('B',2),('C',4),('D',3)]
,[('A',1),('B',3),('C',2),('D',4)]
,[...etc..]]
```

I was able to do this using the following line.

```
AllList = [list(zip(a, p)) for p in permutations(b)]
```

the only problem i'm running into is when the number of elements in my original lists is 11 or greater, it essentially craps out. I was hoping to get a better method of adding my permutations to a list without it giving me out of memory error.

This idea is based off a reality game called "Are you the one?" on MTV. Basically there are 11 girls and 11 guys that have pre-matched by the producers. They have 10 weeks to figure out who they are perfectly matched with. Every week you get to check if a couple is a perfect match or not.

so the idea behind this is to have a list store all of my possible permutations, in this case is 11!. And every time someone is not a perfect pairing, remove all the combinations that were bad matches from my total list.

The goal is to end up with perfect combination of all couples. basically remove combinations from original list of lists, until the correct line is left.

Comment: those are not permutations, thats a product.

Comment: You're getting an out of memory error because the list is bigger than the available memory.  Why do you need it to be a list?

Comment: You have nearly 40 million lists, each containing however many tuples. Crapping out is pretty much expected behaviour.

Comment: is there anyway to store it, because i need to be able to pull the combinations that contain matches.

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha What matches? There seem to be a broader picture you have yet to share.

Comment: You do not necessarily have to store everything, just to find something. For example I could tell you that the 642387464534th natural number is 642387464533, without actually writing all the preceding numbers on a piece of paper. Depending on what you want to achieve it easily may be enough being able to generate lists on the fly.

Comment: Say there is a randomly generated pairing for all 11 elements. For example:
[('A',7),('B',2),('C',11),('D',5),('E',1),('F',3),('G',8),('H',9),('I',4),('J',6),('K',10)].

I want to be able to supply a pairing for example ('A',7), and pull all of the combinations that fit that pairing.

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha You can use a generator expression for this. Generate the matches lazily without having all of them at one time in memory.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye See my edit as to what my idea behind this is.

Comment: Based on your edit, I don't think a list of lists is your best bet. Maybe a graph? And then you can trim edges as needed?

Comment: @mypetlion sorry can you provide some guidance, i'm not familiar with how to graph this.

Comment: I'm not sure I can cover it in a comment. Basically, create a class of Girl and a class of Guy, each containing a complete list of instances of the other (each Guy has a list of all Girls and vice versa). Then, as needed, remove Guys and Girls from eachother's list of potential "The Ones". Again, there's only so much room in a SO comment, so if you need more help, search google for "python graph" or something.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use generators instead of creating the whole list in memory. In fact, as suggested by @joaquinlpereyra, `itertools.product` is a generator but the problem arise when you create the list in memory (i.e. `list(itertools.product(a, b)`).

You can make a generator function out of your problem like so:

```
def product_generator(a, b, excluded=[]):
    for prod in ((x,y) for x in a for y in b): # or itertools.product(a, b)
        if prod not in excluded:
            yield prod
```

In this example, `product_generator` is a generator function and `((x,y) for x in a for y in b)` is a generator expression (as opposed to `[(x,y) for x in a for y in b]` which is a list comprehension—see [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) for guidelines on generator expressions).

You can then iterate over your generator and do something useful with each tuple (e.g. print or append to a file).

Comment: So i created the following generator function. and I noticed that when i don't include the "not in" condition, I'm able to get actual values but otherwise i'm returning empty values.

Comment: What parameter did you use for `excluded`?

Answer (score -1):

You want to use itertools. Specifically itertools.product.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst1 = [i for i in range(40)]
>>> lst2 = [i for i in range(41, 100)]
>>> itertools.product(lst1, lst2)
<itertools.product object at 0x7feedff2fe10>
>>> list(itertools.product(lst1, lst2))
[(0, 41), (0, 42), (0, 43), (0, 44), (0, 45), (0, 46), (0, 47), (0, 48), (0, 49), (0, 50), (0, 51), (0, 52), (0, 53), (0, 54), (0, 55), (0, 56), (0, 57), (0, 58), (0, 59), (0, 60), (0, 61), (0, 62), (0, 63), (0, 64), (0, 65), (0, 66), (0, 67), (0, 68), (0, 69), (0, 70), (0, 71), (0, 72), (0, 73), (0, 74), (0, 75), (0, 76), (0, 77), (0, 78), (0, 79), (0, 80), (0, 81), (0, 82), (0, 83), (0, 84), (0, 85) ..............
```

Comment: 60! permutations of a 40*60 length list? That probably won't solve their Out of Memory Error.

Comment: I believe it will as long as he doesn't try to parse it as a list. I wonder what causes a OutOfMemoryError on such relatively small lists.

Comment: @mypetlion Just don't try to instantiate the entire product as a single list. `product` is effectively just a wrapper around something like `for i in lst1: for j in lst2: yield i, j`. It uses only a constant amount of memory above and beyond what `lst1` and `lst2` are already using at any given moment.

Comment: @chepner Her edit makes it clear that she does plan to instantiate the entire product as a single list.

Comment: There's a difference between "she intended to" and "she needs to"; the list of all product elements is going to be the same size regardless of how she populates it. This sounds a lot like an XY problem; just because problem Y *can* be solved by creating a list of product elements doesn't mean that's the *only* way to solve it.

Comment: @chepner i'm actually a guy :). I can't do product because I need to create a combination line for each pairing. Where as when i do product it lists all the matches with "A" first, and then moves to "B" and so on.

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha Sorry, I never even looked at your name; I just went by the pronoun in the previous comment. :) That said, regardless of *how* you would generate the product, the fact remains that the end result is too large to store in memory as a whole. You need to generate it one element at a time, and decide for each element if it should be ignored or (e.g.) written to disk.

Comment: @chepner I agree with you. I was able to use a generator to create the permutations without an issue using the following. Only problem is trying to iterate through it. 

total = (zip(a, p) for p in itertools.permutations(b))